# Group by array column values in Rails-5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a interesting problem

I want to count by individual values in a array column of a table

for e.g

for User model

```
id |  community_ids
1  |  {2, 4}
2  |  {2, 5} 
3  |  {2, 4}
```

I want to say

```
Community| User count
  2      | 3
  4      | 2
  5      | 1
```

I have a solution

```
User.
  pluck(Arel.sql('unnest(community_ids) as community_id')).
  group_by(&:itself).
  transform_values(&:count)
```

But the problem is i am looping through all the users

Thanks

Comment: Is `Community` a model where User `belongs_to :community`? Or `community_ids` is a datatype array?

Comment: This is why I usually don't use array columns unless i am absolutely sure i wont have to ever apply conditions on it. Because thats not always very easy. Now to your question, you will have to loop through all users anyway, be it in SQL or be it in ruby code, if i were you, i will probably write some custom sql to do this for me. That still wont be very fast of larger datasets.

Comment: Are the values know, and limited in the array column? If so, that will make it a lot easier and effecient.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL version can look something like:

```
SELECT unnest(community_ids) AS community_id, count(*) AS count
FROM users 
GROUP BY community_id;
```

Mapping it to rails AR is also quiet straight forward, it can be done in different ways, i will do the most dump simple way:

```
sql = "SELECT unnest(community_ids) AS community_id, count(*) AS count
FROM users 
GROUP BY community_id"
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a
# results should look something like: [{"community_id"=>2,"count"=>3}...]
```

*PS: This approach is take from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126413/169845).*